# How to create a "boot" state which all other states much transition through?

Tags: ember.js, ember-old-router

I'm building a simple app with a persistent view. This view is always there.
The view depends on some data. Entering the application in a different state should
ensure that view is present with it's data. I thought the best way to do this
would be to create an initial state which calls `connectOulet` to connect the data and view. That way all the subsequent states have to transition through this one. I can't figure out how to get the router to automatically transition to the next state after doing the connecting.

Here is my router (this doesn't work ATM). See comments.

```
Inbox.Router = Ember.Router.extend
  enableLogging: true
  location: "history"
  initialState: "bootUp"

  bootUp: Ember.Route.extend
    root: Ember.Route.extend
      route: '/'
      # All states need to transition through this code
      # How can I transition to root state after this code executes?
      connectOutlets: (router, context) ->
        router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet
          outletName: "list"
          name: "messages"
          context: Inbox.store.findAll(Inbox.Message)

  root: Ember.Route.extend
    showMessage: Ember.Route.transitionTo('root.showingMessage')

    initialState: 'dashboard'

    dashboard: Ember.Route.extend
      route: '/dashboard'

    # Entering this state needs the messages view loaded
    # with data
    showingMessage: Ember.Route.extend
      route: '/:id'
      connectOutlets: (router, context) ->
        router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet
          outletName: "details"
          name: "message"
          context: context
      serialize: (router, context) ->
        id: context.get('id')
      deserialize: (router, urlParams) ->
        Inbox.store.find Inbox.Message, urlParams.id
```

Modeling this behavior with a FSM seems correct to me. Is this the correct way to do such a thing or is there a better way?

Comment: The first impression is that it does not have a root node.  You can only have one root with all other children nested below it.  Both bootup and root states are at root level

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to create a state root state which things transition through. The `root` state itself it not routable. So we have to create a substate for this. Here is my router.

```
# Assume users enters a /

Inbox.Router = Ember.Router.extend
  enableLogging: true
  location: "history"

  # Root application state
  root: Ember.Route.extend

    # This is the state that the others must transition.
    # It's route is "/". It has a nested state called "home"
    # which route is "/". Home's route is relative to "/". 
    # So when a user enters at "/" the "home" state is selected.
    # The router transitions into "index" then "home".
    # When the user enters at "/:id" the user transitions through "index"
    # since "/:id" is a subroute of "/".
    # 
    # This is explained in the router's nested state documentation.
    index: Ember.Route.extend
      route: '/'
      connectOutlets: (router, context) ->
        router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet
          outletName: "list"
          name: "messages"
          context: Inbox.store.findAll(Inbox.Message)
        router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet
          outletName: "details"
          name: "message"
        router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet
          outletName: "filters"
          controller: router.messagesController
          viewClass: Inbox.FiltersView

      showMessage: Ember.Route.transitionTo('showingMessage')

      home: Ember.Route.extend
        route: '/'

      showingMessage: Ember.Route.extend
        route: '/:id'
        connectOutlets: (router, context) ->
          router.get('messageController').set('content', context)
        serialize: (router, context) ->
          id: context.get('id')
        deserialize: (router, urlParams) ->
          Inbox.store.find Inbox.Message, urlParams.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to call connectOutlets in the root Route.  I don't think you can create route/states above or before root like your example.

```
root: Ember.Route.extend
showMessage: Ember.Route.transitionTo('root.showingMessage')
initialState: 'dashboard'

connectOutlets: (router) ->
  router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet
    outletName: "list"
    name: "messages"
    context: Inbox.store.findAll(Inbox.Message)

dashboard: Ember.Route.extend
  route: '/dashboard'

# Entering this state needs the messages view loaded
# with data
showingMessage: Ember.Route.extend
  route: '/:id'
  connectOutlets: (router, context) ->
    router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet
      outletName: "details"
      name: "message"
      context: context
  serialize: (router, context) ->
    id: context.get('id')
  deserialize: (router, urlParams) ->
    Inbox.store.find Inbox.Message, urlParams.id
```

Comment: I've posted my solution. The `root` state is "not routable" according to the documentation. I tried to call `connectOutlet` but the controllers weren't defined yet. I assume this is because of the "not routable" comment. I'm not sure what this means. Either way, my answer works as I'd like.